# IPW recalculating with deterministic treatment

Tags: causality, confounding

Let's assume I want to calculate the ATE for a certain deterministic treatment, such as surgery (i.e., one either had it or not), and I'm interested in a per-protocol analysis.
Note that those who had surgery will always be considered as "treated", but those who did not have a surgery may break their protocol by having the surgery.

This implies that those in the treated group do not have any time varying confounders (nothing can influence their exposure - they are, and always will be, exposed), but for the control group, their probability of having a surgery may change by time-varying confounders.

To adjust for differences between groups I would like to use IPW at baseline, but then I would also like to adjust for time-varying confounders using repeated IPW. My understanding is that I should only apply repeated IPW on the control group, but not on the treated group. Is that correct? And if so, does anyone have some references to justify this approach (either methodological or research examples)?

Thanks!